# Python - Openpyxl - "UserWarning: Unknown extension" issue

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am trying to learn `Python` (day 2) and am hoping to practice with `Excel` books first as this is where I am comfortable/fluent.

Right off the bat I am having an error that I don't quit understand when running the below code:

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("/Users/Scott/Desktop/Workbook1.xlsx")

print(wb.sheetnames)
```

This does print my sheet names as requested, but it is followed by:

```
/Users/Scott/PycharmProjects/Excel/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/openpyxl/worksheet/_reader.py:293: UserWarning: Unknown extension is not supported and will be removed
  warn(msg)
```

---

I have found other questions that point to slicers/conditional formatting etc, but that does not apply here. This is a book I just made and only added 3 sheets before saving. It has no data, no formatting, and the extension is valid. I have no add-ons installed on my excel either.

**Any idea why why I am getting this error? How do I resolve?**

[image]

*Python: 3.7

openpyxl: 2.6*

Comment: *"and the extension is valid"*: Here, **not** the filename extension `.xlsx` are meant. Your workbook has a extension that is **`Unknown`** to `openpyxl`. If you feel it's a BUG, report at Bitbucket.

Comment: I literally installed Python yesterday - I’m not qualified to *think* anything is a bug yet lol. So, the warning message is not talking about the literal file extension but some other type of extension?

Comment: The closesd Issue on Bitbucket are [unknown-extension](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/1050/unknown-extension)

Comment: It's not an error, it's a an informational warning.

Comment: Is there now way to clear it? @CharlieClark it’s quit annoying since I’m just testing so I’m printing just about every line.

Comment: You can suppress warnings in Python.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I had a similar issue. I developed an application which read and write Excel files. It woked well on my Windows computer, but then I tried to run it on a friends mac. It showed the same error. I could "fix" it by changing the configuration of the workbook, like this:

```
import openpyxl as op

wb = op.load_workbook(file, read_only=True, data_only=True)
```

But, as you can see, you can only read Excel files with this configuration. At the end, I realized that my friend didn't have Microsoft Office installed on his computer. Install it truly solved my problem.

Answer (score 15):

This question was from a couple years ago but I'm encountering it now with openpyxl and require a fix, as the warning is confounding and misleading to my end users.

The warning from openpyxl comes via the stdlib warnings library, which can be suppressed.

```
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
```

That's the "hit it with a hammer" approach. More granular levels of warnings suppression can be found here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html

Comment: This solution even though a bit harsh, solves it for  the `pandas` function `read_excel` as well :)

Comment: This definitely doesn't  _solve_ the problem... but it does make it go away without any seeming downside.

Answer (score 9):

[Python - Openpyxl - "UserWarning: Unknown extension" issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54976991/python-openpyxl-userwarning-unknown-extension-issue)

To understand the error, you need to know what's inside an XLSX file.  The best way to take a look is to change the extension to zip and open that. Inside you will see a file called `[Content_Types].xml` and directories for the other content. If you check out the XML in Content_Types you will see a `<Types ...>` tag containing other tags like this:

```
<Default Extension="png" ContentType="image/png"/>
<Default Extension="rels" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml"/>
<Default Extension="xml" ContentType="application/xml"/>
```

Note the "Extension" property. This is what the warning refers to. In the example above, my file included `Extension="png"` - the unknown extension.
For me, it was enough to specify `read_only=True` and the error went away eg:

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file, read_only=True)
```

I could also fix the issue by copying everything except the images to a new workbook and saving that.  After checking, the xml in the new workbook no longer contained the png property.

Note, reading into pandas with `pd.read_excel` uses openpyxl and generates the same "Unknown extension" error but there is no way to pass through the `read_only` parameter. You can suppress the specific warning with:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', category=UserWarning, module='openpyxl')
```

Comment: @gnoodle, I agree. Also if you encounter this warning in pandas, you can apply the same fix by using `pd.read_excel(..., engine='openpyxl', engine_kwargs={'read_only': True}` (requires pandas 2.1+).

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly the problem I encountered just now..

And to my situation (not to everyone) I discovered that you just need to close your excel and rerun the code, very simple.

If this doesn't work, you can refer to other answers.

Thanks